# Engine noies in Chevrolet Aveo

Tags: engine, chevrolet, noise, aveo

I have a Chevrolet Aveo car. And now it is making noise from the engine compartment. Tickling noise increases as I accelerate the car. What should I do?

Comment: Check your oil level. Is it in normal range?

Comment: Does this noise only happen when the car is moving (rolling) or also when it is sitting still (not rolling)?

Answer (score 1):

Noise that increases with vehicle speed is typically something related to the wheels, tires, hubs or driveshaft, not the engine.

- inspect your tires for a rock stuck in the thread
- while driving, try to notice if the clicking sound goes away when you steer left, or steer right (if yes, it suggests a hub is worn out)
- have the front suspension inspected (some tire or alignment shops do this for free) and steering for loose or worn out components
- have your wheels checked for proper balancing

Comment: Ticking sounds that increase with speed are not always tires. The OP needs to tell us if this noise is present when the vehicle is parked to know for sure. If it is ticking while sitting still, it could be engine related.